# Slow Net on Wi-Fi, but full speed on wired, only on one device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have two laptops, two Xboxes and one desktop.

I have a 30 mbps broadband plan with a turbo boost of 40 mbps.

I can easily download on a wired connection at full speed, but downloading on my laptop is only max 20mbps. The other laptop and the Xbox get the full 40 mbps speed.

And it's the overall speed, because I have an NFS share that I access on my desktop and if I'm transferring from it, my internet speed decreases, whereas total max speed is always 20 mbps on Wi-Fi for me.

I own a Dell N7010.
I have a Netgear WRN2000v2 running DD-WRT bridged with my TWC modem SBG6580.

EDIT:
I have dell n7010 with a WiMax 6250 wireles controller.... my Config is ISP> Motorola SBG6580 > Netgear WNR2000v2 (DD-WRT) > Devices

PS: on ubuntu i manage to get full 3 MBps from net and while accessing NFS shares i get a good 6 MBps [when i'm ion same room as the AP]

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop only has a B/G card and not an N card, then 20mbps is about the best you can expect.  Upgrade to N if you want faster wireless speeds.

For more information, see the following Answer:
[What's the maximum actual bit rate of an 802.11g connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/302943/whats-the-maximum-actual-bit-rate-of-an-802-11g-connection/302951#302951)

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search, it appears that your Dell n7010 have a 802.11 b/g card. Your Xbox 360 has a 802.11 b/g/n carg. I will bet your other notebook has a 802.11 b/g/n card.

Although the nominal velocity of B/G cards is 54mbps, the max I could get on my setup was 12Mbps (router is a WNR2000v1).

That is probably why you are not getting more than 20mbps on your Dell.

See related question (which I asked and answered myself): [Wireless Connection not maxed out but "slow"](https://superuser.com/questions/166333/wireless-connection-not-maxed-out-but-slow)

HTH

Comment: nopes it use to get it previously.... it happend wen i got a new router

Comment: this dell is not even an year old and in settings i can see b/g/n ... the other laptoip infact is 3+ years old

Comment: @SarveshLad I suggest you to point that it start happening when you got your new router, it may help giving more accurate answers. Add the specs of both of your WiFi cards too.

Comment: I have dell n7010 with a WiMax 6250 wireles controller....
my Config is
ISP> Motorola SBG6580 > Netgear WNR2000v2 (DD-WRT) > Devices

PS: on ubuntu i manage to get full 3 mbps from net and while accessing NFS shares i get a good 6 mbps

Comment: @SarveshLad You should update your Question with these details, like your card model and the fact that you got better speeds with your previous AP. Also, in this last comment, did you mean 3 or 30? 6 or 60? In your Question you said you had 30 mbps service, but here you're saying "full 3 mbps", which makes me wonder which is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry i have a 30 mbps or 3 MBps [i converted megabits to mega bytes]